# C++ extern usage between dll and application

Tags: c++, dll, extern

Please forgive me if this is a stupid question but I am following a book and it isn't working.
I have an game engine, which lives in a dll. It has a couple of external functions to be used in the actual game application:

```
extern void game_preload();
```

This is all perfect and dandy but when I go to build the all I get an error:

```
Undefined reference to `game_preload()'
```

Why is this? how can I get it to build out the dll so I can implement those functions in the application?

The book I am following is called "Advanced 2D game development" and it doesn't mention there being an issue.

EDIT: I read the book wrong and I was supposed to make a static library rather than a dynamic one. But may I ask is there anything similar to the "extern" usage for dynamic libraries?

Comment: Use `__declspec(dllexport)` in DLL and `__declspec(dllimport)` in application? (`__declspec(dllimport) void game_preload();`) (It works only with static link.)

Comment: If you follow the book's instructions on setting up the VC project then you'll create an EXE project, not a DLL project.  Writing your own game_preload function is required, that's how you create a custom game.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to link the static or dynamic library (for MSVC this is a file with the "lib" extension, for GCC this is either "a", "o" or "dll" depending on your system, etc.). The `extern` keyword is meant to be used to tell the compiler some variable can be found in another compilation unit (like a forward declaration, but for variables). Function prototypes are always `extern`anyway, so it can be omitted there.

There's also the special case of using `extern "C"` to explicitly tell the compiler to handle some code as C rather than C++ (e.g. to link to C style functions inside C++ code).

Edit: Creating and using a static library is even easier to do. [You can read up on this including some examples here.](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/gcc/create_lib.html) However I think it should be explained in the book at some part, unless you're supposed to not use any library so far (as mentioned in one of the comments).

Comment: so do I remove "Extern"? they are in the dll, so I can't link anything because I am building the dll

Comment: Consider it obsolete. You'll have to link the library, but to tell you how to do it, it would be important to know your compiler.

Comment: mingw, gcc are my compilers. And what library do I link? the only thing I'm linking is SDL and Opengl

Comment: If you've created your own static library, you'll have to link it just like you link SDL and OpenGL (see link I added to my answer).